# What do the culture loaded words mean in this paragraph?

Tags: word, culture

《很想很想你》依靠人设的丰富和突破，使得剧集有一种贴合现实的甜度感！在剧里，从初识的“以声定情”，到相见后的种种试探，再到双向奔赴后的彼此宠溺，莫青成和顾声的情感推进步步为营、恰到好处，大量生活细节的铺陈让这场童话爱情既浪漫又写实，毫无强行煽情、狗血桥段，更没有油腻戏码。

Can anybody help to explain 人设 甜度 双向奔赴 煽情 狗血桥段 油腻戏码?

Roughly I estimate 人设 to be background information, 甜度sweetness or honeymoon, 双向奔赴to meet each other halfway...

Answer (score 3):

人设 is short for 人物设定 (character setting), like his appearance, personality, etc.

甜度 is literally "degree of sweetness". In romance novels, "sweetness" refers to the portrayal of interactions between a couple. A work that heavily displays affectionate behaviors of cute couples is called "sweet".

双向奔赴 is literally "running toward each other". It means a two persons simultaneously develop feelings toward each other, and result in a happy relationship.

煽情 is 煽动情感, that is, to incite feelings in the reader. It refers to plots that strongly move the reader. Here 强行煽情 means using unnatural, awkward plots to move the viewer.

狗血桥段, 桥段 is a plot segment, and 狗血 is a vague adjective that means the plot is unnatural, comic, impossible in real life, etc.

油腻戏码, 油腻 originally means greasy, but sometime around 2019 it became a slang. Here you can treat 油腻戏码 as having similar meaning to 狗血桥段. It roughly means the actions of the character make people feel embarrassed if they were performed in real life.

Comment: Instructive. What is the origin for 狗血 and 油腻? I do not see any connection of "unnatural, comic, impossible" to these two phrases.

Comment: For 狗血, see here: https://zh.m.wikipedia.org/zh-hans/%E6%B4%92%E7%8B%97%E8%A1%80

Comment: Initially, the slang 油腻 was referring to a bunch of negative stereotypes associated with men in their 40s, including negligence of body image, leading to obesity and poor hygiene, hence "greasy". Sometime in 2019 its meaning was shifted or generalized to all behaviors that evoke the same kind of feeling in people as those stereotype characteristics, which is the meaning used here.